# confused with bufferedreader and inputstream..correct me

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, bufferedreader

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\acontent.txt"));
        String a="";
        int c;
        Reader r = new InputStreamReader(br);
        while((c=r.read())!=-1){
            a= a + Character.toString((char)c); 
        }
```

trying to write a code to read from file and save the whole content in a string and i want to do this only this way , dont want to use scanner class or other method plz suggest a way where i m going wrong in this..

Comment: What problem did you encounter?

Comment: two errors in code........The constructor InputStreamReader(BufferedReader) is undefined............The constructor BufferedInputStream(BufferedReader) is undefined

Comment: Well, yes, an `InputStreamReader` basically turns an `InputStream` into a `Reader`, by wrapping it in logic to convert bytes to characters.  It doesn't make sense to try and construct it from something that's already a `Reader`.

Answer (score 0):

Oh, this is a terrible way to convert a file into a String, but as you say you don't accept another "method" of doing this, here you go.

```
try {
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader( new FileReader("D:\\acontent.txt") );
        String a = "";
        int c;
        while ( ( c = br.read() ) != -1 ) {
            a = a + Character.toString( ( char ) c );
        }
        System.out.println( a );
    } catch ( Exception e ) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

By the way, please use spaces in your source code!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use an InputStreamReader because it will not provide you more functionalities than the BufferedReader. The better way to do what you want should be something like this:

```
try {
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("D:\\acontent.txt"));
    StringBuilder strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    String line = br.readLine();
    while(line != null){
        strBuilder.append(line);
        line = br.readLine();
    }
    return strBuilder.toString();
....
```

If you want to use the read() method and retrieve each character one by one, then you can use your FileReader directly.

All implementations of the Reader interface have a read() method returning a char. Only BufferedReader has the readLine() method to return a complete line.